# Should I store chili crisp in the refrigerator?

Tags: oil, refrigerator, garlic

Generally speaking I only refrigerate things that say something along the lines of "refrigerate after opening" or "keep refrigerated" on the label. I opened a new jar of chili crisp today, used some, and am now wondering if I should refrigerate it.

It has a lot of words on the label, but nothing that indicates that it needs to be refrigerated. On the other hand, it does say no preservatives, and its ingredients include oils and garlic. I know there's a risk of botulism if you (for example) put some garlic in a container of olive oil and leave it at room temperature. Is there a similar risk for this product? Should I refrigerate this jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chili crisp [does not have to be refrigerated](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/asin/B0051D84JU).  However, if it will take you months to finish off a jar, [refrigeration may keep the flavor](https://www.thespruceeats.com/storing-chinese-sauce-and-seasonings-695083) better.